# PDF.js - split pdf into pages and re-build multiple files

Tags: node.js, pdf.js

I am currently working on a Node.js project. One of the actions required is to read the text of a pdf document and then split the document into separate files.

As I have been using pdf.js for all other pdf parsing in this project, I was hoping to complete the above requirement using it as well.

Reading the PDF and its text content is relatively straightforward.

For example -

```
function GetWords(pdfUrl){
var pdf = PDFJS.getDocument(pdfUrl);
return pdf.then(function(pdf) { // calculate total count for document
     var maxPages = pdf.pdfInfo.numPages;
     var countPromises = []; // collecting all page promises
     for (var j = 1; j <= maxPages; j++) {
        var page = pdf.getPage(j);
        var txt = "";
        countPromises.push(page.then(function(page) { // add page promise
            var textContent = page.getTextContent();
            return textContent.then
            (
                function(page)
                { // return content promise

                    for(var i=0;i<page.items.length;i++)
                    {
                        var txtadd = page.items[i].str

                        txt += txtadd.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9:;,.?!-() ]/g,'');
                    }
                    return txt.split(" ").length; // value for page words
                });
        }));


     }
     // Wait for all pages and sum counts
     return Promise.all(countPromises).then(function (counts) {
       var count = 0;
       //counts.forEach(function (c) { count += c; });
       return count;
     });
});
}
```

However, I can't seem to find any examples of building a PDF from one / or more of its pages. Ideally, I would want to use the `pdf.GetPage(j)` to get an array of the pages required. Then push these into a new document and save this new document to disk.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a separate library to perform the splitting. http://pdfhummus.com/. So in combination with the PDF.js i was able to get the desired result.